# .Net Maui MVVM Navigate and Pass Object Between Views

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I am struggling to pass an object from one view to another using .Net Maui and a UI independent MVVM pattern.

Most or all MAUI examples I have found to date use and promote MVVM. They also tend to store the View-Models within the UI project and utilize MAUI App Shell navigation directly. This in my opinion and understanding potentially omits some of the benefits of MVVM as View Models would not work with other UI projects.

I have attempted to create a working example* with the View Models, Models and Services being in a separate UI independent project and referenced by the UI project(s) which contain the Views. [Sample Project Published to GitHub](https://github.com/RabbitAth/MauiMVVMNav) I would like to update the project with a solution so it can be a working example.

[image: Project Layout]

I am specifically stuck where when clicking on a single object from a list of objects it opens a detail view but the object is not passed successfully.  In this case my example utilizes a list of customer orders and I am attempting to open the order in a detail view when clicking on an order from the order list.

##### My problem lies somewhere between the XAML binding to the GoToOrdersCommand, how the command is implemented, and Order object passed to the Order View-Model.

Why do I have both a DelegateCommand and RelayCommand, I am not sure.  Different examples I have viewed have used these names, I am not sure if one name is correct.  Or if they should be combined into one class. I believe the only significant difference for this example is that RelayCommand accepts an object as a parameter.

**Orders View-Model**

```
    namespace Orders.Common.ViewModel
    {
        public class OrdersViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders { get; } = new();
    
            private readonly OrderDataProvider _orderDataProvider;
            private IOrderNavigation _navigationService;
    
            public RelayCommand<Order> GoToOrdersCommand { get; }
    
            private Order _order;
    
            public OrdersViewModel(IOrderNavigation navigationService)
            {
                Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
                _orderDataProvider = new OrderDataProvider();
                _navigationService = navigationService;
    
                _order = new Order();
    
                GoToOrdersCommand = new RelayCommand<Order>((order) => OrderDetails(_order));
    
                Load();
            }
    
            public void Load()
            {
                var orders = _orderDataProvider.GetAllOrders();
                Orders.Clear();
    
                foreach (var order in orders)
                    Orders.Add(order);
            }
    
            public void OrderDetails(Order order)
            {
                if (order == null)
                    return;
    
                _navigationService.NavigateToOrderAsync(order);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Order View-Model**

```
public class OrderViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Order _order;

        public Order Order
        {
            get => _order;
            set
            {
                if (_order != value)
                {
                    _order = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private OrderDataProvider _orderDataProvider = new OrderDataProvider();

        public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; }

        public ICommand SaveOrder { get; set; }


        public OrderViewModel()
        {
            _order = new Order() { OrderID = -1, Customer = "", OrderDate = DateTime.Now };

            SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, () => CanSave);
        }

        public OrderViewModel(Order order)
        {
            _order = order;

            SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, () => CanSave);
        }

        public bool CanSave => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerName) && CustomerName.Length >= 3;

        public void Save()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int OrderID
        {
            get => _order.OrderID;
            set
            {
                if (_order.OrderID != value)
                {
                    _order.OrderID = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string CustomerName
        {
            get => _order.Customer;
            set
            {
                if (_order.Customer != value)
                {
                    _order.Customer = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CanSave));
                    SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public DateTime OrderDate
        {
            get => _order.OrderDate;
            set
            {
                if (_order.OrderDate != value)
                {
                    _order.OrderDate = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Inherited UI Specific Navigation**

```
    namespace TestOrders.Navigate
    {
        public class OrderNavigationService : IOrderNavigation
        {
            public void NavigateToOrdersAsync()
            {
                Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OrdersPage));
            }
    
            public void NavigateToOrderAsync(Order order)
            {
                Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OrderPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Order", order } });
            }        
        }
    }
```

**RelayCommand**

```
namespace Orders.Common.ViewModel.Command
{
    public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _execute;
        private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**Orders View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestOrders.Pages.OrdersPage"
             Title="OrdersPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Orders.Common.Model;assembly=Orders.Common"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Orders.Common.ViewModel;assembly=Orders.Common"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:OrdersViewModel">

        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Orders" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <CollectionView
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Order">
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Frame HeightRequest="70">
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:OrdersViewModel}}, Path=GoToOrdersCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                
                                <Grid Padding="0" ColumnDefinitions="20,*">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding OrderID}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Customer}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Being new to .Net Maui, XAML based UI's, MVVM patterns and inexperienced with additional topics such as interfaces and delegates there are likely best practices or coding conventions I have missed. I am also trying to avoid utilizing the MVVM community toolkit or other toolkits until I have a better understanding of MVVM and how the interfaces and commands function.*

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this

```
GoToOrdersCommand = new RelayCommand<Order>((order) => OrderDetails(_order));
```

should be

```
GoToOrdersCommand = new RelayCommand<Order>((order) => OrderDetails(order));
```

`_order` is a new instance that you create on the preceding line, NOT the instance being passed in from the view's binding

Comment: I believe I tried that when troubleshooting.  Changing _order to order gives a cannot convert from 'object' to 'Orders.Common.Model.Order' error.  I believe it has to be an instantiated object and not an object or type.  When placing a break point on '_navigationService.NavigateToOrderAsync(order);' the order is a generic new instance and not the order clicked on in the UI from the list.

Comment: `(order)` should be the value passed in `CommandParameter`.  If you are getting an error then you need to chase down that error and fix it.

Comment: Commenting out `_order = new Order();` and changing the line to `GoToOrdersCommand = new RelayCommand<Order>((order) => OrderDetails((Order)order));` seemed to be part of the solution.  The proper selected order is now being passed from the UI to the _navigationService.  I still have a problem where the OrderViewModel is not having its Order property set by the navigation service.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes

Comment: That did the trick, was missing the `[QueryProperty(nameof(order), "Order")]` in my Order View code behind file.  Also ran into a slight issue where QueryProperty does not receive its value until after the Order View constructor has run.  So I believe a separate property and method is required in the View.  Updated the github repo with the working changes, but cannot guarantee it is the cleanest solution.  Thank you for your help!  I had been stuck for a while on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Change to OrdersViewModel Constructor**

```
public OrdersViewModel(IOrderNavigation navigationService)
{
    Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
    _orderDataProvider = new OrderDataProvider();
    _navigationService = navigationService;


    GoToOrdersCommand = new RelayCommand<Order>((order) => OrderDetails((Order)order));
    GoToNewOrderCommand = new DelegateCommand(NewOrder); // Additional navigate without object

    Load();
}
```

Additional Command method to navigate to a New/Empty Order Detail for reference added to the OrdersViewModel

```
private void NewOrder()
{
    _navigationService.NavigateToOrderAsync();
}
```

Updated Order Navigation

```
public class OrderNavigationService : IOrderNavigation
{
    public void NavigateToOrdersAsync()
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OrdersPage));
    }

    public void NavigateToOrderAsync(Order order)
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OrderPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Order", order } });
    }

    public void NavigateToOrderAsync()
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OrderPage));
    }
}
```

**OrderPage View Code Behind File**

Added QueryProperty, a field and method to create an OrderViewModel if an Order object is provided.

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(order), "Order")]
public partial class OrderPage : ContentPage
{
    public Order order
    {
        set
        {
            Load(value);
        }
    }

    public OrderPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new OrderViewModel();
    }

    private void Load(Order order)
    {
        if (order != null)
            BindingContext = new OrderViewModel(order);
    }
}
```